# Log of people/ip's who connected to my machine through remote desktop

Tags: 10.04, remote-desktop, logging

My network has a static IP. And I could see some un-intended user tried to access my machine through Remote Desktop. Where can I see the log of the same?

Using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh.. Vino does not keep logs :(

Its a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/330310)

Comment: Can this be closed?

Comment: Yes, couldn't mark the answer earlier (2 days policy!)